# как поменять namespace в xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd

Есть `xml` и получаю я его, скажем, из "сферического вакуума". В нем есть тег с атрибутом `xsi:type`:

```
<out:Declarant xsi:type="out:RequestAccount">
```

Есть и описывающий этот `xml` - файл `xsd`:

```
<xs:complexType name="RequestContact">
        <xs:extension base="tns:BaseDeclarant">
              <xs:sequence>
                 ................. 
               </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="xsi:type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
```

вот здесь как раз таки проблема, `<xs:attribute name="">`- не может содержать различные знаки типа тире черточки т.е.:

```
   <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NCName"/>
```

его тип = `NCName`, и он не хочет чтобы `name` содержал невалидные символы.
Как обойти эту дилемму? я не могу попросить дать мне правильные `xml` или самому менять все приходящие `xml` или написать свой namespace для xsd или как? подскажите люди добрые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут `xsi:type` принадлежит пространству имен `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. Вы не можете его объявить у себя в схеме, но можете разрешить элементу содержать атрибуты из этого пространства имен при помощи элемента [`xsd:anyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256443(v=vs.120).aspx)

```
<xs:extension base="tns:BaseDeclarant">
    <xs:sequence>
       ................. 
     </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      processContents="lax" />
</xs:extension>
```